# Cake 2.4 Not returning results even though it finds results

Tags: mysql, model, cakephp-2.3

php 5.4 - Seems to work fine on a 5.3 install.
$this->NodeBlock->find('all');

Will not return any results. However, find('list'), paginate, find('first'), all work.

Even when I plug the generated query into my sequel editor that returns results. The debug log shows rows but nothing is returned. This happens for all models.

Here is the query returned when debugging the query log.

```
SELECT `NodeBlock`.`id`, `NodeBlock`.`node_id`, `NodeBlock`.`title`, `NodeBlock`.`description`, 
`NodeBlock`.`cta_link`, `NodeBlock`.`cta_text`, `NodeBlock`.`image`, `NodeBlock`.`style`, Node.id
    FROM `mydatabase`.`node_blocks` AS `NodeBlock` 
    LEFT JOIN `mydatabase`.`nodes` AS `Node` 
        ON (`NodeBlock`.`node_id` = `Node`.`id`)  WHERE 1 = 1
```

Any suggestions? Is this just failing to return the results for some reason? Let me know if you need more information.

[image: query log debug]

thanks!

Comment: ho you use the data returned by `$this->NodeBlock->find('all');`? Can you please post a little more code?

Comment: @arila I am not entirely clear on your question. 1. I do not get any data back from find('all'). 2. I don't know what more code you need. Find all just simply returns no data. At any location on the site as well as any controller or model configuration. On a remote server (running php 5.3), it is pulling data back so it must be a setting within my local server. I just discovered this but I am using 5.4 on my local machine.

Comment: I guess you do something like this to pass your data to your view: `$nodeBlocks=$this->NodeBlock->find('all'); $this->set('nodeBlocks', $nodeBlocks);`. Or there is something else that you do before passing your data to the view? Can you post the result of `print_r($this->NodeBlock->find('all'))`?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am not getting data back and I am not loading the view. So I am running this in the controller. **debug($this->NodeBlock->find('all')); exit;** All I see is the usual debug statement and line number with no data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't fully understand what was wrong but I think it was just not outputting the data. It started working again. I know this is a poor answer but I really don't know what changed and I doubt anyone would be able to shed much light on the subject since it is so unique.